# Удаление данных с ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Имеется listView с адаптером. Данные получаются с php+mysql. Возможно ли реализовать удаление объекта из ListView. Ответы, найденные на просторах интернета не смогли реализовать это (в моем случае) java-Class

```
        public class InfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

            private ListView lvOrders;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            lvOrders = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvOrders);
            DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()

            .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)

            .build();
            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .build();
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

 public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<OrderModel>> {

        @Override
        protected List<OrderModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String finalJson = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("orders");

                List<OrderModel> orderModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0;i<parentArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    OrderModel orderModel = new OrderModel();
                    orderModel.setId_order_desc(finalObject.getInt("id_order_desc"));
                    orderModel.setId_quantity(finalObject.getInt("id_quantity"));
                    orderModel.setId_date_start(finalObject.getString("id_date_start"));
                    orderModel.setId_date_finish(finalObject.getString("id_date_finish"));
                    orderModel.setEmail(finalObject.getString("email"));
                    orderModel.setImage(finalObject.getString("image"));
                    orderModel.setType_print(finalObject.getString("type_print"));
                    orderModel.setType_color(finalObject.getString("type_color"));
                    orderModel.setType_pay(finalObject.getString("type_pay"));

                    orderModelList.add(orderModel);
                }
                return orderModelList;
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if( reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<OrderModel> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            final OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
            lvOrders.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
        }
    }
    public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        private List<OrderModel> orderModelList;
        private int resource;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        public OrderAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<OrderModel> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            orderModelList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            }
            ImageView ivOrderIcon;
            TextView tvId;
            TextView tvEmail;
            TextView tvPrint;
            TextView tvColor;
            TextView tvPay;
            TextView tvQuantity;
            TextView tvDS;
            TextView tvDF;

            ivOrderIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            tvId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            tvEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
            tvPrint = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrint);
            tvColor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvColor);
            tvPay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPay);
            tvQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
            tvDS = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDS);
            tvDF = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDF);

            if (orderModelList.get(position).getImage().contains("http")){
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(orderModelList.get(position).getImage(), ivOrderIcon);
            } else {
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgPath + orderModelList.get(position).getImage(), ivOrderIcon);
            }

            tvId.setText("ID: " + orderModelList.get(position).getId_order_desc());
            tvEmail.setText("Email: " + orderModelList.get(position).getEmail());
            tvPrint.setText("Type Print: " + orderModelList.get(position).getType_print());
            tvColor.setText("Type Color: " + orderModelList.get(position).getType_color());
            tvPay.setText("Type Pay: " + orderModelList.get(position).getType_pay());
            tvQuantity.setText("Quantity: " + orderModelList.get(position).getId_quantity());
            tvDS.setText("Date Start: " + orderModelList.get(position).getId_date_start());
            tvDF.setText("Date Finish: " + orderModelList.get(position).getId_date_finish());

            return convertView;
        }
    }


}
```

Один из способов, найденных на просторах интернета, я не смог проверить:

```
   ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String item = lvOrders.getItemAtPosition(0).toString();
            orderAdapter.remove(item);
            orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

По причине того, что не имею понятие куда следует это записать. Так как при вставке в "onPostExecute"/ "onCreate" выдает следующую ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.runkdown.db_02.InfoActivity$JSONTask.onPostExecute(InfoActivity.java:226)
                                                                                at com.example.runkdown.db_02.InfoActivity$JSONTask.onPostExecute(InfoActivity.java:156)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                                                at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваши данные вам надо хранить в переменной активити.
2. В нужный момент вам надо из них удалить элемент
3. После этого уведомить об этом адаптер